# Stuff function resulting in Msg 8120, Level 16

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a production database `DataProd` with a table `IPSubnets`. This table is made of only two columns : an *ID* (Not used here) and a subnet address (`IP_Subnets0`).

Now, I want to associate each IP_Subnets0 entry with the name of the physical site where it is located. As a single site can have multiple subnets, I also want to group the results by Site with a concatenated list of associated subnets.

What I did so far is the following :

- I have started with the declaration of a **SiteList** table because I can't create new, permanent tables into my database. You can notice that *Site3* has two associated Subnets.
- Then, I select the `SiteName` from `@SiteList` and uses `Stuff` to act like `Group_Concat` would do on `IP_Subnets0`.
- Finally, I do a `Group By SiteName`.

Code:

```
DECLARE @SiteList TABLE (SiteID Int Not Null Primary Key Identity(1,1), 
                         SiteName VarChar(30), 
                         Subnet VarChar(15)
                        )

INSERT INTO @SiteList 
VALUES ('Site1', '192.168.10.0'), ('Site2', '192.168.20.0'),
       ('Site3', '192.168.30.0'), ('Site3', '192.168.40.0')

SELECT DISTINCT
    SL.SiteName, 
    Subnets = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ','+ IP_Subnets0 
                     FROM dbo.v_RA_System_IPSubnets
                     WHERE IP_Subnets0 = SL.Subnet
                     FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM
    @SiteList SL
GROUP BY
    SL.SiteName
```

When I do this, I get an error

> Msg 8120, Level 16 
>   '@SiteList.Subnet' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

on the line of the `WHERE` clause that is inside the `STUFF`.

I don't understand what the problem is. I have already used this `Stuff` piece similarly (Though not with a table declared like I did here but rather with an actual table from the database) and everything went well.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not aggregating any data here - run your query as you have it, sans the last line - i.e. drop the `GROUP BY` statement.

**Updated Query**

```
DECLARE @SiteList TABLE (SiteID Int Not Null Primary Key Identity(1,1), 
                         SiteName VarChar(30), 
                         Subnet VarChar(15)
                        )

INSERT INTO @SiteList 
VALUES ('Site1', '192.168.10.0'), ('Site2', '192.168.20.0'),
       ('Site3', '192.168.30.0'), ('Site3', '192.168.40.0')

SELECT DISTINCT
    SL.SiteName, 
    Subnets = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ','+ IP_Subnets0 
                     FROM dbo.v_RA_System_IPSubnets
                     --WHERE IP_Subnets0 = SL.Subnet  -- your where clause
                     WHERE SiteName = SL.SiteName     -- you want to match on sitename         
                     FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM
    @SiteList SL
```

Comment: Ah yeah, my bad. I wonder how I ended thinking I was doing some kind of aggregation here. What would you suggest to get the result I want then (One row per site. Every associated subnets concatenated in a single column) ?

Comment: you need to adjust the where clause to look at the sitename and not subnet - I'll update the answer in a sec

Comment: @Tuttu I updated the query - let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I figured it out myself a few minutes later but I then got caught in a meeting and was unable to post it here. Thanks for your time. :)

Comment: ok, though if it is helpful, please consider upvoting and/or marking it as the answer.

Comment: I already upvoted it (But my vote aren't displayed because I have less than 15 Rep). I forgot to mark it as the answer but it's not done. Thanks again. :)